# How to show at listbox2 value by select value from listbox1 (by id) c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, listbox

How to show at ListBox value by select value from listbox1 (by id), at asp.net c#...

example:

```
listbox1 (car name) :  Fiat , subaro, honda

listbox2 (car type..after fiat selected at box1) : punto sx, punto gx. punto blabla-x (...)

listbox3 (car year...after type selected) : 2000-2002 (....)

listbox4 (items for the car that selected at lstbox1 2 and 3 .. : volta, wheel (...)
```

i have database (sql) with tables: CarName, CarType , CarYear, Items

thanks!

Comment: homework? are you having a specific problem implementing the example you showed?

Comment: i failed at the start... i have succed connect the two table with where ... (LINQ) ..  but i don't know how to cuntinue with the code behind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to bind the second listbox to a var in the selectedindexchanged event of the first listbox.  Example (using dropdownlistboxes in this case):

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x =
        [LINQ query here]
    DropDownList2.DataSource = x;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "[fieldname]";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ID";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

If you know how to write the query and assign the correct field to the DataTextField (the one that will show up in the 2nd listbox) you're all set.

Comment: Remind that resulting (set of) object has to contain exact properties name, i.e. `ID` and `[fieldname]`.

Comment: thanks you all.
your answer looks the best. i made something else - where staetment with enabled = false; for each ddl .. and at the cs file i made for each ddl to turn enabled = true; .

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) AjaxControlToolkit control.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Just make sure you have the id in the Tag. Here's an example edited from a recent (WinForms) homework assignment I had:

```
private void lstCarName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstCarName.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        int CarId = (int)lstKlanten.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
        MakeCarTypeListBox(id);
    }
}
```

MakeCarTypeListBox could look something like:

```
private void MakeCarTypeListBox(int carId)
{
    lstCarType.Items.Clear();
    CarType[] carTypes = CarType.CarTypesByCarNameI(carId);
    for (int i = 0; i < carTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(carTypes[i].Id.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(carTypes[i].CarTypeName);
        item.Tag = carTypes[i].Id;

        lstDetail.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that I used WinForms and home-made entity classes though, so your code will probably be somewhat different...